# interface override a method of an other interface

Tags: java, interface

given

```
   public interface Crud<T> {
        public T get();
        public T add(String json);
        public T update(String json);
        public T delete(String json);
    }

   public interface AddressCrud extends Crud<AddressResponse> {
        public AddressResponse get();
        public AddressResponse add(String json);
        public AddressResponse update(String json);
        public AddressResponse delete(String json);
    }
```

If a class implements AddressCrud ? will we have to implements 4 methods or 8 methods?

Now if we write :

```
   public interface AddressCrud extends Crud<AddressResponse> {
        @Override
        public AddressResponse get();
        @Override
        public AddressResponse add(String json);
        @Override 
        public AddressResponse update(String json);
        @Override
        public AddressResponse delete(String json);
    }
```

I know @Override is used to override the implementation of a method, but in the case of an interface is the @Override make a sense ?

Now If a class implements AddressCrud in this case ? will we have to implements 4 methods or 8 methods?

update: for your information:
I am using a feign clients and I need to declare interface per client .. I have several feign clients ... there are annotation that are different between the interfaces .. this is why I am trying to make a common interface that I called Crud

Comment: You don't need to redeclare the methods in the child interfaces. Just declare them in the base interface. See [the docs](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#advanced-usage)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare any method in `AddressCrud`. It's sufficient to just extend `Crud<AddressResponse>`.
Tha't the whole point in generics. 
In fact, you don't need even to declare `AddressCrud`, you can just have the class implement `Crud<AddressResponse>`.
In either case, you will have only 4 methods to implement

Comment: no in fact it is not my point, because i m using a feign clients and I need to declare several interface per client ... there are annotation that are different between the shared interfaces .. this is why i mtrying to make a common interface

Answer (score 0):

The tag `@Override` is meaningless in your case. BTW, the implementation classes for `AddressCrud` will implement for 4 methods.

Comment: So the abstract methods of the interface are "overrided" .. thanks